# How to select data with multi indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, series

I have got the following settings:

Dataset1 of type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`:

```
Attr1
12
7
8
```

Dataset2-data-probability of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

```
0.001
0.5
0.0001
```

My goal is to select the values from dataset1 where the probability is < 0.02 in Dataset2. Indeed Dataset1 and Dataset2 have the same cardinality. 
My attempt is the following:

1. define a condition: `my_preferred_data = np.asarray(np.where(Dataset2 < 0.02))`
2. get the data as `dataset1[my_preferred_data]`

The error I am getting is `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key.`
Please, could I ask any help? Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `type(Dataset1.index)`? Additionally, what about `Dataset2.shape`?

Comment: Thanks for the promptly reply. it is <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>

Comment: Thanks, what about `Dataset2.shape`?

Comment: Thanks. it is (61,) when running Dataset2.shape

Comment: `Dataset1[Dataset2.flat < .02]` works for me.

Comment: and for me too. Many Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried casting as a data frame and then resetting the index? i.e. df = pd.DataFrame(Dataset1).reset_index()?

Answer (score 0):

You could have directly done this:

`Dataset1[Dataset2 < 0.02]`

This would have given you the answer.